# Update/upgrade a program installed via tar.gz

Tags: upgrade, updates, tar

I've installed Postman the following way:

```
wget https://dl.pstmn.io/download/latest/linux64 -O postman.tar.gz
sudo tar -xzf postman.tar.gz -C /opt
rm postman.tar.gz
sudo ln -s /opt/Postman/Postman /usr/bin/postman
```

There is a newer version available, but the auto update does not work.

Can I update to the new version using the newer .tar.gz file? How do I properly do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have "installed" Postman by just unzipping some already build binaries of it, which then you linked into you bin folder. If you want to update the program, you will have to download the new version manually and follow the same procedure.

Alternatively, you can install postman from a repository (you should get rid of the installation you manually made though, beforehand). That will ensure that every time you `sudo apt-get upgrade` the program will stay up to date (In other words it will sync with the repository and will always update to the latest version that the repository is providing). Check this [link](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/09/install-postman-app-easily-via-snap-in-ubuntu-18-04/) on how to install Postman through aptitude.

Answer (score 0):

Just first remove the existing:

```
sudo rm -fr /opt/Postman
```

And then use the same above commands less the 'ln' command since you already have the symlink in place.